# Consequence of dimensions of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ given by $T(v)=Av$. Which of the following is correct?

(A) If $T$ is onto then $rank(A)=m$.

(B) If $T$ is injective then $rank(A)=m$.

(C) If $rank(A)=n$ then $T$ is onto.

I think (A) is true, because $dim(ImT)$ is given by the dimension of the row space of $A$ which implies $rank(A)=m$.

As for (B) - if $T$ is injective, $kerT={0}$. This implies $rank(A)=n$ and not $m$, right?

As for (C) - $rank(A)=n$ implies $ker(T)={0}$ so that $T$ is injective, but not necessarily onto. Am I right?

Looking forward to your verification.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is the *column space* of $A$ which corresponds to $Im T$, so part (a) is most naturally related to the dimension of that.

Comment: Great, thanks for helping me out in this one! :)